# Run macro using controlpopup vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that will create a popup window that will allow me to navigate  between pages of a workbook. So far I have been able to populate a controlpopup that runs a simple macro, but I would like it to be able to accept variables (aka the sheetname) to avoid having to write a bunch of different macros. Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub Custom_PopUpMenu_1(Mname As String)
    Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup
    ' Add the popup menu.
    With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=Mname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
         MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
            .Caption = "Menu Control"
              With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Button 1 in menu"
                .FaceId = 71
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro"
            End With
        End With 
    End With
End Sub
```

This runs the macro 'TestMacro' but am not sure how to write it so that it will accept a string variable. My other though is that in each .OnAction to update a global variable that is the sheetname, but am unsure of how to do that either.
Let me know if you can help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (at least, it works for a shape on a worksheet)

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'TestMacro ""blah22""'"
```

...but if what you want is to navigate to a particular sheet then right-clicking on the "VCR" control to the left of the sheet tabs is the easiest built-in way...

If your parameter is in a variable you can do this:

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'TestMacro """ & stringvariable  & """'"
```

Comment: Tim, the VCR control is useless if the worksheet is hidden :)

Comment: If you had more time to answer a follow up question that would be great. The code above worked great for a defined string (in your example "blah22"); however if you wanted to add a string variable how would you do that. I attempted to write this code but the macro is not getting called:

.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'TestMacro " & stringvariable & "'"

Answer (score 0):

Your `testmacro` should launch a userform which would have a `ComboBox` and a `CommandButton`

The logic is, when the userform initializes, it will store all the sheet names from the current workbook in the `ComboBox` and you can use the `CommandButton` to navigate to that sheet.

Here is an Example

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wsName As String

    If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        wsName = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)

        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = True
        End If

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]